# Convert a Date field into Week Number in IBM DB2

Tags: db2

I have a Date field **(CHAR Datatype**) which has values in this format: YYYYMMDD.

For example 20140729.

I want to convert it into a Weeknumber in format YYYYWKNO

For example, the result would be 201432.

How this can be done in **IBM DB2?**

Answer (score 4):

Luckily for you, DB2 has some pretty good date formatting functions. Although the links for the documentation are for DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, it will also work on DB2 for z/OS.

You can use [`TIMESTAMP_FORMAT()`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-153&lang=en) to convert your `CHAR` field to an actual date, which you can then use [`VARCHAR_FORMAT()`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-179) to format it in the way you wish:

```
SELECT
    VARCHAR_FORMAT(
         TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(
             '20140801'
            ,'YYYYMMDD'
         )
        ,'YYYYWW'
    )
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

There are two different formats for "week", one is `WW`, which will give the week based on a week beginning with January 1 and ending January 7, and `IW`, which will give the [ISO Week.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week). Please see the documentation page for `VARCHAR_FORMAT` for the other formats available.

Answer (score 0):

The following gets week 31 instead of 32. But overall I think it is a good solution for this problem:

```sql
SELECT    TO_DATE('20140801', 'YYYYMMDD') AS MYDATE
        , YEAR(TO_DATE('20140801', 'YYYYMMDD')) * 100 + WEEK(TO_DATE('20140801', 'YYYYMMDD')) AS YYYYWKNO
FROM      SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```